cokernel of acyclic chain complex of projective modules after tensoring
Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring, $(\mathbf F,d)$ be an acyclic chain complex of projective $R$-modules and $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module. Let $i$ be an integer and put $N:=\text{coker}(d_i:\mathbf F_i\to \mathbf F_{i-1})$.
If $\mathbf F\otimes_R M$ is also an acyclic complex, then is it true that $N\otimes_R M \cong \text{coker}(d_i\otimes M:\mathbf F_i \otimes M \to \mathbf F_{i-1}\otimes M)$ ?
